# jQuery hasClass call not working for button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a button that hides or shows images based on which class is currently applied to the button, and adjusts the text to show what the button will do.
I have created a button with class "on" in html

```
 <button class="on">Hide images</button>
```

Then I set up my jQuery to check if the button clicked has class "on" and act accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("on")){function(){
                $(this).html("Show images");
                $(this).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
                $("img").hide();
            }
        }

        else{function(){
                $(this).html("Hide images")
                $(this).addClass("on").removeClass("off");
                $("img").show();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Currently nothing happens if I click the button other than it going in and out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't need anonymous function declarations for conditional statements, only your event bindings. The conditional portion should simply be `if (...) { //code } else { //code }`

Comment: Vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: ^ And this is, in fact, the problem. You're just conditionally defining a function; either remove the function declaration or turn it into an IIFE (by adding `()`).

Comment: And have a look at toggle and toggleClass

Comment: `$('button').on("click",function(){
  $("img").toggle();
  var show = $(this).hasClass("on");
  $(this).html(show?"Show images":"Hide images");
  $(this).toggleClass("on",!show).toggleClass("off",show);
});`

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help, I was quite certain it wasn't working while I didn't have the functions inside the conditionals so I added them to be safe and it still wasn't working. Anyway, removing them started it working so I'm a little confused but thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is coming from your anonymous functions being initialized inside of your conditional. There's no reason, that I can see, for them. This should work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("on")){
            $(this).html("Show images");
            $(this).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
            $("img").hide();

        }

        else{
            $(this).html("Hide images")
            $(this).addClass("on").removeClass("off");
            $("img").show();

        }
    })
});
```

Notice that if/else no longer have the anonymous functions, and instead just runs the jquery.

Comment: Want to include a comment, with a reason for down voting?

Comment: Possibly because it was already answered in a comment 10 minutes ago and the question can be deleted

Comment: was not I who downvoted, but this is my new exact code (and it works) so I'm not sure why you were downvoted

Comment: @mplungjan Acknowledged, thanks. I added the answer for clarity, next time I'll use more discretion.